# Why am I getting result consisted of more than one row error, when finally one row is returned?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Upon running the following procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `portaldb`.`is_optional_type_assigned`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `is_optional_type_assigned`(userId int, optionalPlanId int)
begin
        if userId is not null and optionalPlanId is not null then
            // Will return multiple rows
            select conv.FeatureName from planallocation as pa
            left join subscriptioninfo as si
            on si.SubscriptionId = pa.SubscriptionId 
            left join plans as pl
            on pl.PlanId = pa.CurrentPlanId
            right join conversiontable as conv
            on conv.ConversionId = pl.OptionalFeatureId
            where si.UserId = userId and 
            conv.FeatureType = 'optional' into @featureList;

           // Will return single row
            select conv.FeatureName from conversiontable as conv
            right join plans as pl
            on conv.ConversionId = pl.OptionalFeatureId         
            where conv.FeatureType = 'optional' and 
            pl.PlanId = optionalPlanId into @featureName;

            if @featureName in (@featureList) then
                select true as isAssigned;
            else
                select false as isAssigned;
            end if;
        end if;
    end$$

DELIMITER ;
```

I am getting:

```
    Error Code : 1172
Result consisted of more than one row
```

error. What could be the reason for this? The result from the first two select statement is assigned to the variable and then compared if one set contains another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error because MySQL requires that a query being selected into a variable must return exactly one row - return zero or more than one row results in an error. So your first query, which you comment returns multiple rows, will cause the error.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html

you could possibly change the query to something like :

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(conv.FeatureName) from  .....
```

to get a single comma separated list result & then search for @featureName in that list - but that may depend on the number of results returned. Otherwise you need to restructure your two queries - possibly something like this (note I have incorporated Gordon's suggestion on parameter naming) :

```
/ Will return single row
select conv.FeatureName from conversiontable as conv
right join plans as pl
on conv.ConversionId = pl.OptionalFeatureId         
where conv.FeatureType = 'optional' and 
pl.PlanId = in_optionalPlanId into @featureName;

select IF(count(conv.FeatureName)>0,true,false) from planallocation as pa
left join subscriptioninfo as si
on si.SubscriptionId = pa.SubscriptionId 
left join plans as pl
on pl.PlanId = pa.CurrentPlanId
right join conversiontable as conv
on conv.ConversionId = pl.OptionalFeatureId
where si.UserId = in_userId and 
conv.FeatureType = 'optional' and
conv.FeatureName = @featureName;
```

It may be possible to reorganise it into a more efficient query or even a single query.

Comment: Will `if @featureName in (@featureList)` work? It is not working at the moment.

Comment: If the reorganisation I have suggested works - the second query results in the true/false result so the "if @featureName in (@featureList)" is not required.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not do what you think it does.  A cardinal rule when using parameters:  Name them differently, so they are obvious in the code.

When you write:

```
where si.UserId = userId and
```

This is interpreted as:

```
where si.UserId = si.userId and
```

I would suggest that you start with a more readable and useful:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS portaldb.is_optional_type_assigned$$

CREATE DEFINER = root@localhost PROCEDURE is_optional_type_assigned (
    in_userId int,
    in_optionalPlanId int
)
BEGIN
    if in_userId is not null and in_optionalPlanId is not null then
        . . .
END;$$

DELIMITER ;
```